# SharePoint online list form settings restoration

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, list-form

I was having SharePoint list form with JavaScript enabled.

I tried to do some checks and mistakenly deleted the form in web part area, now i am getting error.

Please guide me how to restore the previous settings in SharePoint form.

Note: Already used default form only

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using? How many web parts were added on form page initially? Did you delete JS web part (content editor or script editor) or list form web part?